# Underbraces using tikzmark

Tags: tikzmark, underbrace

I'm trying to get some sort of nesting braces for some math notes that I'm typing, this is the code that I'm using:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, french]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,intersections, decorations.pathreplacing,shapes,snakes}
\begin{document}
\tikzmark{a}
\[
\tikzmark{c}U^{T}\tikzmark{d}\;\quad\quad\tikzmark{e}A\tikzmark{f}\;\quad.\quad\tikzmark{g}U\tikzmark{h}
\]
\tikzmark{b}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}]
\foreach \i / \j in {a/0, b/10pt, c/0, d/0, e/0, f/0, g/0, h/0} \coordinate (\i) at ([yshift=\j]{pic cs:\i});
\draw [decorate] (b -| d) -- (c |- b) node[midway,below,yshift=-5pt] {$1 \times n$} coordinate(k);
\draw [decorate] (b -| f) -- (e |- b) node[midway,below,yshift=-5pt] {$n \times n$} coordinate(l);
\draw [decorate] (b -| h) -- (g |- b) node[midway,below,yshift=-5pt] {$1 \times 1$} coordinate(m);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}, yshift=-15pt]
\draw [decorate] (b -| l) -- (k |- b) node[midway,below] {$n \times n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the output that I'm getting:

[image]

I would like to instead have the second brace under the `1 x n` and `n x n` is there any way I can do that? I do have to go even lower to have another brace encompassing the next line which would be `1 x n` to be braced with `1 x 1`.

If you have any other ideas on how I could accomplish it, maybe without TikZ, I am more than open to suggestions.

Edited to add what was asked in comment.

Comment: please extend your code snippet to complete small documnet beginning with `\documentclass{...}` folowoed by needed packages and your equation, and ending with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your MWE is not complete, I can't reproduce your output.

However, `tikzmark` is useless here, there is `\underbrace` from `\amsmath` package which could be also nested.

Maybe this is what you want to achieve (you could also add some `\quad` where you like or any other kerning, if you want):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \[
    \underbrace{%
        \underbrace{%
            \underbrace{U^{T}}_{1\times n}\cdot\underbrace{A}_{n\times n}
        }_{1\times n}\cdot\underbrace{U}_{n\times 1}
    }_{1\times 1}   
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks you so much, didn't realize you could nest with \underbrace

Comment: I love the waterfall of `underbrace`'s <3.